# Petición POST en Angular

Tags: ajax, angular, post

Me gustaría llamar a un archivo php desde Angular pasando el parametro usuario y clave .

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient, HttpHeaders} from '@angular/common/http';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-api-login',
  templateUrl: './api-login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['../app.component.css']
})
export class ApiLoginComponent implements OnInit {
  usuario:String;
  clave:String;
  register:Boolean;
  constructor() { 
    this.usuario="PrecaNuevo"
    this.clave="PrecaNuevo";
    this.register=false;
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    var conAjax = $http.post("pgular/php/login.php", {usuario: this.usuario, clave: this.clave});
    conAjax.success(function(respuesta){
        console.log(respuesta);
    });
  }

}
```

Recibo el error: `ERROR ReferenceError: $http is not defined`

He empezado hoy con Angular, seguro que faltan algunas cosas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te recomiendo que eches un vistazo al [tutorial](https://angular.io/tutorial) de angular.

Así, de forma rápida, `$http` no existe en tu componente. Angular funciona sobre la inyección de dependencias, es decir, para utilizar el cliente http de angular lo debes inyectar en el constructor:

```
constructor(httpClient: HttpClient) {
    ...
}
```

Para hacer la llamada seria:

```
this.httpClient.post(URL, params...)...
```

Y para que esto funcione debes importar el módulo HttpClientModule en tu AppModule.

Pero lo más importante en mi opinión es que realices el tutorial que te he enlazado arriba.